# Scanf Seg Fault

Tags: c, io

I'm working on my assignment for my C course, and I'm trying to take in the user's input and store it in a variable to use for later in my code. Here's what my main function looks like,

```
int main() {
    // Variables here
    char* inputLine[10];

    do {
        printf("Insert number....");
        scanf("%s\n", inputLine);
        // More stuff here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code gives me a bunch of warnings, `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char **' [-Wformat]`, and if I change the variable declaration to,

```
char* inputLine = NULL;
```

When I execute my code I get a seg fault, can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong, and the differences of what happens in the memory when I'm initializing this variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char* inputLine[10];`

--> is an array of ten pointers to `char`

printf's format `%s` expects argument of type `char *`, but you're providing it as type `char **`

Just use

`char inputLine[10];`

To avoid possible buffer overflow you should use

`scanf("%9s", inputLine); //Notice the size with %s`

`9` only because C string are null terminated (`'\0'`) so one extra byte for it goes at end

Comment: +1 and harden that with a length specifier on the format specifier to protect against buffer overflow.

Answer (score 3):

```
 char inputLine[10];

 do {
    printf("Insert number....");
    scanf("%9s\n", inputLine);
    // More stuff here
} while( //some condition);
```

Comment: To stay on the secure side better do `scanf("%9s\n", inputLine);`.

Answer (score 0):

However if you edit your code and remove `*` you get answer, but normal array deprecated, nowdays, programmers use `vector`,  `normal array in C not safe` :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    vector<string> inputLine;
```

You can define with every `data type`:

```
vector<int> myvar;
```

Or you can define multidimensional `vector`:

```
vector< vector <int> > myvar;
```

Comment: ummm...Did you see `C` tag ?

Comment: I saw, but some of same question are for beginners and i preffer to teach them .